# extern variable value initialization after its uses in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, export, extern

I am using some variable through export and extern like below:

text.h

```
namespace xyz{
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) extern const abccore::id kTextClassID;
}
```

in text.cpp

```
namspace xyz
{
 extern const abccore::id kTextClassID("ValueClass");
}
```

now in other file
MacStartup.cpp

```
#include "text.h"
__attribute__((constructor))
void MacWorkStartup()
{
auto var = abccore::kTextClassID;
//and use this.
}
```

Now order should be like first kTextClassID gets its value then MacWorkStartup should be able to use this. but it first coming to MacWorkStartup function where I found some garbage value then it get its value in cpp file. what to change that in MacWorkStartup it will have string Value.It was running fine in our last year release but due to xcode upgrade or something(I dont know), its not running now.

Comment: Initilaization of global and namespace variables are ordered in definition order in a single translation unit. The order of initialization between translation units is indeterminate. Have you thought about refactoring your code so it doesn't rely on compiler-extensions (like `__attribute__((constructor))`), perhaps by calling you "startup" function first thing in the `main` function (when all global and namespace variables will have been initialized)?

Comment: And what is the underlying problem you need to solve by having a "constructor" function like `MacWorkStartup`? Why do you need it? What is the use-case?

Comment: this is legacy code. I dont think refactoring would be possible . use case here is there is some UI componennt which they will use this var variable.and create some UI.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of global across several translation units in indeterminate. So you have to fix your code:

- Move `MacWorkStartup` definition in same file than `kTextClassID` definition.
- Call `MacWorkStartup` in `main` instead of (non-portable) attribute constructor.
- Use delayed initialization of `kTextClassID`:

  ```
  namespace xyz{
  __attribute__((visibility("default"))) const abccore::id& GetTextClassID()
  {
      static const abccore::id instance{"ValueClass"};

      return instance;
  }
  }
  ```
- if relevant/possible, `constexpr` (and `consteval`) might replace `static`.

Comment: moving MacWorkStartup to that file can't be done. as this is in different folder. while other file similar to MacWorkStartup are also using same variable. I have given thought to your Third option , but I was looking for something which could enforce MacWorkStartup to call text.cpp first. due to that it will come to memory.